# /Users/.../.zshrc:source:69: no such file or directory: /Users/.../.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I uninstalled `zsh` on my mac, but now I receive this error message every time I start a terminal. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/363555/424671). Basically, it didn't change my **login shell** back to bash.